# Which drill bits for breaking veroboard tracks

Tags: pcb

I have to use a veroboard/stripped PCB. Which drill bits will help in breaking tracks?

Comment: One where the non-cutting area at the tip will fit in the hole, and the flutes are ultimately wide enough to cut the whole track, and the angle blunt enough to do so without digging.  A step drill with a cylindrical pilot that fit entirely in the hole and a more trepan like cutting edge would be ideal.  It does not actually need to be round - you could make your own with a file (and optionally a lathe) - ideally use hardenable drill rod, though phenolic PCB is pretty soft.  It's probably best to rotate the drill by hand, maybe putting it in a handle.

Comment: What should be the diameter of the drill bits?

Comment: This was just explained...

Comment: Since cone angles tend to be same, anything << track spacing and try reverse spin before drilling a huge hole. or use precision care or drill precisely with  hand drill tool or dremel grinder and vacuum.  Fluted cutting edges prevent grabbing, so it looks like a 3-4mm router cone tipped bit

Comment: I mean i need a value for its diameter

Comment: You've been told both how to determine the requirement from the properties of a board that are known only to you, and also that it is not particularly critical.  Electronic projects will generally require that you become comfortable solving problems with quite a bit less information to work from.

Comment: If you don't have the hand tool, use a 4mm Dremel cone grinder and vacuum. or 4mm drill bit in reverse.

Comment: It is obvious that no attempt to solve this problem has been made by the OP.

Comment: The diameter could usefully be the same as the track spacing.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

*Figure 1. Veroboard cutting tool by Vero.*

Vero make a tool specifically for the job. The tip angle is just right so it finds the centre of the hole and cuts without grabbing the board.

Answer (score 2):

Use a 4mm diameter bit, preferably carbide, 2nd preference cobalt-steel, 3rd preference high-speed steel (HSS) bit. Make a handle for it if you want and press the bit in.

Or use the official cutter as @Transistor suggests, though some find the handle is a bit small for their hands.

Comment: Carbide drills are extremely fragile and so not really suited to use outside carefully controlled circumstances.  Cobalt is added to tool steel primarily for heat resistance which wouldn't be an issue if the work is done by hand.

Comment: @ChrisStratton A 4mm diameter carbide drill is *not* fragile. 0.8mm-1.5mm maybe. Cobalt-steel drills are harder, tough and stay sharp longer even if heat isn't an issue. Compare the Rockwell numbers. A lot of HSS drill bits are junk and are not even all that sharp- including the ones with fancy-looking TiN coating.

Comment: The problem with carbide in that size is not so much breaking the shaft as chipping the edge that does the actual work.  Certainly, there are low quality tools, and a wide variety of tool steels, but fundamentally the purpose for which cobalt is added is not of any real use here.  And far before that point, a conventional twist drill isn't really the right shape anyway.  Something that is, and is made out of any reasonable HSS alloy (with or without cobalt) is also probably going to be easier to resharpen by hand.  The asker's money is wasted seeking a carbide or special alloy *twist drill*.